# Why doesn't this C code (writing to unix pipe) iterate infinitely?

Tags: c, pipe

I'm asked to say how many iterations will happen (in the second while loop). My answer would be infinite, but when I run this code, it does 10912 iterations and the program simply stops printing (but it does not seem to end as I still have to press ctrl+c to exit it).

Why does that happen? I could not find that particular number to be the limit/maximum of anything.

```
char string [] = “hello”;

void main()
{
    char buf[1024];
    char *cp1, *cp2;
    int fds[2];
    cp1 = string;
    cp2 = buf;
    while (*cp1)
    *cp2++ = *cp1++; 
    pipe(fds);
    int i = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        write(fds[1], buf, 6);
        i++;
        printf("i: %d", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably exceeded some buffer and it's blocking until there's more room.

Comment: Do you have anything on the other side reading the pipe? If not, it makes sense the pipe has an internal buffer and won't let you write until it's empty.

Comment: It should be `int main()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're writing to the pipe, but never reading from the other side of it. As such, the data goes into a pipe buffer, and once the buffer is full any additional writes block, causing your program to hang since nothing ever unblocks it by reading from the pipe. On your system it would appear that the pipe buffer size is 64k (65,536 bytes) or slightly less, since it succeeds in writing 65,472 bytes before stopping.